# Highlight particular days in calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

Hi I am trying to implement a calendar application using  Android CalenderView. I am able to view the calendar. And now I am implementing and other activity, user input form, where user inputs events on particular dates.

Creating the form was the easy part but I am having trouble in highlighting the days in the calendar (just with different color).

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What days do you want to highlight? What have you tried so far? Please be more specific and post some code.

Comment: This link might help you. It is fully customizable calendarview sample. https://github.com/ahmed-alamir/CalendarView

Comment: Right now I am using the code from this repository https://github.com/square/android-times-square.git.  I this allows me to select the days on the calendar by clicking on individual dates. I want to select individual dates through a form.